# How to use @ColumnTransformer encryption and decryption with native query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

I need to encrypt all values in mysql database table

```
   | userId |      email   | userAge | firstName| lastName  | userType |
   |--------|--------------|---------|-----------|----------|--------- |
   |    1   |john@gmail.com| 20      | John      | Smith    | 1        |
```

My user class as following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User{

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "userId ")
private int userId;

@Column(name = "firstName")
private String firstName;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "lastName")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "userType ")
private String userType ;

// getters and setters
}
```

I am planning on using @ColumnTransformer

```
 @Column
  @ColumnTransformer(
   read = "cast(aes_decrypt(email, 'secretkey') as char(255))", 
   write = "aes_encrypt(?, 'secretkey')"
   ) 
  private String email;
```

This is working on encryption. And, there are lot of usage of nativeQueries. But method like this return just the encrypted email.

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true , value = "select * from user where userId =?1")
  Optional<User> getUserByUserId(String userId);
```

And I also have other methods that use email like this :

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true , value = "select * from user where email=?1 and 
 firstName =?2")
 Optional<User> getUserByEmailAndFirstName(String email, String firstName);
```

For that I tried to use something like this :

```
 select * from users where email= aes_encrypt(?, 'secretkey') and firstName =?2
```

This is also not working.

If anyone know how to resolve this issue it will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a native SQL query something like this:

> select * from user where email IN (SELECT
> HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('your_email@gamil,com', 'secret_key')));

Basically, you have to convert your email to AES encrypt so that DB can find the exact match.